# LISTAR LOS DATOS Y LOS QUE NO TIENEN PONERLO SIN DATOS SQL

Tags: sql, sql-server

BUENO SI ME PODRÍAN APOYAR:

tengo 2 tablas:

La primera tabla es Tipo_documentos la cual esta relacionada con la tabla usuario con los datos:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

La cuestión es que cuando hago el left join me lista solo los datos que tienen

```
select 
 u.nombre_usuario, 
 td.nombre_docmuento,
 CASE WHEN td.nombre_docmuento IS NOT NULL THEN 'SI TIENE DATOS'END AS TINE_DATOS 
from tipo_documento td
left join usuario u on td.id_docu = u.id_docu
```

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

EN FIN LO QUE NECESITO ES QUE ME LISTE LOS USUARIOS Y QUE LOS DOCUMENTOS QUE NO TIENEN, ME PONGA COMO NO DATOS, ALGO ASÍ CON TODOS LOS USUARIOS
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

SERA POSIBLE?? HACER ESO
AGRADEZCO DESDE YA SU CORDIAL AYUDA

Comment: Y con los otros **Joins** ya has probado??

Comment: Tu diseño de tablas está mal. Necesitas una tabla adicional para la relación entre usuarios y tipos de documentos para poder relacionar varios tipos de documentos a cada usuario. También es buena costumbre poner las definiciones de tablas y datos de prueba como código.

Comment: hola gracias por contestar, si ya probe, pero sigue saliendo lo mismo que con el left

Comment: hola luis cazares, si de hecho esta es la tabla que arme para más o menos explicar de que trata, pero donde la usaré esta el BD de la empresa, pero no puedo mostrar pero esa si tiene una tabla adicional que hace referencia a ambas tablas, si entiendo mil disculpas, soy nuevo en esto.

Comment: Entonces pon la estructura según como la necesitas, porque la consulta es distinta en cada caso

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
select
 u.NombreUsuario,
 t.NombreDocumento,
 IIF(u.id_docu = t.id_docu, 'Tiene datos', 'No tiene datos') as Estado 
from Usuario u, TipoDocumento t
order by u.NombreUsuario
```

Lo que se hace aquí es un **producto cartesiano entre las dos tablas**, es decir se combina cada registro de la **tabla Usuario** con todos los registros de la **tabla TipoDocumento** obteniendo de esta forma todas las combinaciones posibles de registros entre las dos tablas.

Posteriormente en la **claúsula select** utilizamos la **función iif**, la cual a través de la condición:

```
u.id_docu = t.id_docu
```

determinará si los registros están o no relacionados, de cumplirse la condición estarán relacionados y se devolverá **'Tiene datos'**, de no coincidir se devolverá la cadena **'No tiene datos'**.

Comment: Muchísimas gracias, eres lo máximo, alguien que esta empezando a programar te lo agradece muchísimo :).